# Azure Batch Node Start Task Program Not Found

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have set the resource files in the proper place in blob storage to then copy over to the proper folder location/file.exe name and have the Start Task command for the batch node pool as:

```
cd /d D:\Users\JRETemp

jre.exe INSTALL_SILENT=Enable /Q
```

However, after the node join the pool/reboots, the same error appears. ie. "Could not find program: UserError".

After the node starts up, I did not set the node to fail if start task fails, I can locate the program in the proper location in the file path and of the proper name.

Why would this continually fail?

Answer (score 0):

Your start task should wrap your [commands in a shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-api-basics#task):

```
cmd.exe /c "cd /d D:\Users\JRETemp && jre.exe INSTALL_SILENT=Enable /Q"
```